# How to sort XML elements in parent element?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to change the order of elements in one parent element. So it is easy to get sorted elements.

```
myXML.Elements("Issue").OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("id").Value));
```

But I need to return this sorted collection back in myXML XElement without affecting it's structure.

How to do this?

Comment: Imagine `<foo><Issue id="3" /><ABC /><Issue id="1" /><DEF /></foo>` - what would you want the result to be?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Parent element includes only <Issue> elements. But I need to save attributes of this parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
// No need to specify "Issue" if that's all that's in myXML. Prefer explicit
// attribute conversion over "manual" parsing
var orderedIssues = myXML.Elements().OrderBy(x => (int) x.Attribute("id"));
myXML.ReplaceNodes(orderedIssues);
```